# Refactor R.filter and R.map to just R.reduce in pointfree style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce, pointfree, ramda.js

I've started learning [Ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/docs) and functional programming and am very interested in functional composition using the pointfree style of programming, but I am having difficulty getting my head around some of it and I'm hoping someone can help illustrate:

Suppose I have a list of people - I want to only get the people between an inclusive age range of 13-19 (teenagers). Then, I want to map each person to either the return value of the person's `getName()` method (if it exists), else their `name` property. Then, I want to call `.toUpperCase()` on the names.

If I were using regular JS prototype methods, I wouldn't use `Array.prototype.filter` to get the teenage users and then `Array.prototype.map`. For performance reasons, I'd use `Array.prototype.reduce`, the body of which would be guarded by a conditional that checks if each iterated item meets the criteria for a teenager. This way, I'm iterating one less time. [Elijah Manor has an article about this on his blog](http://elijahmanor.com/reducing-filter-and-map-down-to-reduce/).

Here's the pointfree Ramda code I've come up with using `R.filter` and `R.map` (this works as expected):

```
var people = [
  { name: 'Bob', gender: 'male', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Jones', gender: 'male', age: 15 },
  { name: 'Alice', gender: 'female', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Carol', gender: 'female', age: 32 },
  { name: 'Odu', gender: 'male', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Fred', gender: 'male', age: 55 },
  { name: 'Nicole', gender: 'female', age: 29 },
  { getName: function() { return 'David' }, gender: 'male', age: 23 }
]

var getUpcasedTeenagerNames = R.pipe(
  R.filter(
    R.propSatisfies(R.both(R.lte(13), R.gte(19)), 'age')
  ),
  R.map(
    R.pipe(
      R.ifElse(
        R.propIs(Function, 'getName'),
        R.invoker(0, 'getName'),
        R.prop('name')
      ),
      R.toUpper
    )
  )
)

getUpcasedTeenagerNames(people) // => ['JONES', 'ALICE']
```

My question is - how would I re-write the following native version of the above algorithm to use pointfree Ramda.js?

```
var getUpcasedTeenagerNames = function(people) {
  return people
    .reduce(function(teenagers, person) {
      var age = person.age
      if (age >= 13 && age <= 19) {
        var name
        if (typeof (name = person.getName) === 'function') {
          name = name()
        } else {
          name = person.name
        }
        teenagers.push(name.toUpperCase())
      }
      return teenagers
    }, [])
}
```

I've tried doing it with `R.scan`, looked at using `R.reduced` and `R.when` but I'm afraid I might be missing the point a little bit.

For your convenience, I've included this code on the Ramda REPL: http://goo.gl/6hBi5k

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would break the problem down a little differently.  I would use Ramda's `R.__` placeholder to fill in the first argument to `R.lte` and `R.gte`, so that they read better.  I like to alias this with a plain underscore, so this will read `R.both(R.gte(_, 13), R.lte(_, 19))`, which I find more readable.  Then I would separate out the function which finds the name on a person.  That's clearly a stand-alone bit of code, and pulling that out makes the main code much more readable.

Finally, and here's the big thing, if you learn a bit about [Transducers](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2014/8/6/transducers-are-coming), you will learn a trick that stops the need to worry about the intermediate collections that are the possible performance problem in the initial technique.

```
var _ = R.__;
var findName = R.ifElse(
  R.propIs(Function, 'getName'),
  R.invoker(0, 'getName'),
  R.prop('name')
); 

var getUpcasedTeenagerNames = R.into([], R.compose(
  R.filter(
    R.propSatisfies(R.both(R.gte(_, 13), R.lte(_, 19)), 'age')
  ),
  R.map(R.pipe(findName, R.toUpper))
));

getUpcasedTeenagerNames(people); //=> ["JONES", "ALICE"]
```

Now I wouldn't worry about the performance at all, unless I've found a performance problem and shown that this section of code is a major culprit.  But if I had, then I could fix it by using transducers, and since both `map` and `filter` already work, all I need to do is to switch the direction of my composition (here by changing from pipe to compose) and wrap it up with [`into([])`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#into).

If you're interested, here's [an article](http://simplectic.com/blog/2015/ramda-transducers-logs/) on user transducers in Ramda, and [another good intro](http://phuu.net/2014/08/31/csp-and-transducers.html) to transducers.

If I find a little time, I will see if I can convert your code into a points-free solution, but please don't make a fetish out of points-free.  It's a useful
technique in some circumstance, but we shouldn't feel driven to use it where it doesn't easily fit.

Comment: Wow, transducers are an awesome concept - clearly I have a lot more to learn. Thanks!